# Is it safe to use `eval` with the `with` statement this way?

Tags: javascript

Template actually comes from an index.html file from the same directory.
Context can contain user input.

```
const context = { id: 1 };
const template = '<html><body>${id}</body></html>';
with (context) {
  return eval(`\`${template}\``);
}
```

I know about XSS protection.

I'm looking for examples of how to break this solution, is there any way a user input can run backend code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: two things you never want to use: with and eval :)

Comment: I believe this is safe to run server-side, but you may still want to look into a templating module (I.E. nunjucks, pug) to have full templating functionality including template inheritance, includes, logic/loops, automatic escaping (XSS protection), etc.

Comment: `
<table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
        ${
            ['1', '2', '3'].map(e => ``
            <tr>
                <td>
                ${e}
                </td>
            </tr>
            ``).join('\n')
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
`

I have loops :)

Comment: @AttilaVarga Sure, but that's not very readable (especially if you ever want to have nested loops/logic) and you're still missing some of the most important features... Without template inheritance you will need to repeat a lot of code on every template for instance. Even if you only have one template I highly recommend using a full-fledged templating engine instead of reinventing the wheel and adding features as you need them.

Comment: Using nunjucks is as simple as `npm install nunjucks` and then `return nunjucks.renderString( template, context );` where your template looks like `'<html><body>{{id}}</body></html>'` and your context is the same as the one in your question.

Comment: @Paulpro JSX works the same way, and this is not reinventing the wheel, it is the wheel itself.

Comment: JSX is an overall bad idea. I can't fathom why anyone would want to mix a language as powerful and complex as JavaScript with their templates.

Comment: Because it shortens code, the only thing that relates to the number of bugs is LoC.

It's ugly I agree. XML was a horrible idea back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how `context` is supplied with values, it may be possible to set `context.template`. This would change the variable identifier `template` to refer to the property `context.template`, and have that property's value passed into `eval`.

Therefore, you could have server-side code execution via a `context` property like

```
template: "${alert(1)}"
```

Alternately, if a `context` property could be given a function value, then setting `context.eval` would allow immediate execution of that function. (This is less likely to be feasible, however, since user input is much more likely to be treated universally as a string.)

You could avoid both of these issues by doing `delete context.template; delete context.eval;` before entering the `with` block.

Comment: Ta, it definitely broke it :D and without with?

(The context is provided by the code though, keys can contain user input)

Comment: @AttilaVarga Assuming you dropped `with` and wrote your templates like `<body>${context.id}</body>`, etc? I think that would be safe (but I can only ever be perfectly sure that something is breakable, never perfectly sure that it's safe!). The vector I'd try without `with` is to get an interesting value in `context.__proto__` to see its properties: e.g., make `context.__proto__ = global` and find a template with a `context.process` access. But if I'm only allowed to store simple string values, I don't think that will allow me to do anything nasty or interesting with `__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to use eval.

If you want to interpolate the string you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Even then you should be sanitizing use input to avoid XSS. A simple way to sanitize a string is to read the input as text which would escape the input and then dump the content into the template placeholder.

```js
const context = { id: 1 };
const template = `<html><body>${getHTMLSafeText(context.id)}</body></html>`;

function getHTMLSafeText(content) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.textContent = content;

    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: There is no feature in js to parse template literals apart from eval and yeah I use XSS protection if I print HTML.

Comment: I'm looking for examples of how to break this solution, is there any way a user input can run backend code?

Comment: "There is no feature in js to parse template literals apart from eval"? That's patently false. Run the following in the console: ``console.log(`The date is ${new Date()}`)``

Comment: Sure. You could do it that way ( what do you mean by `evaluate` here ? `eval` ?)

Comment: You have one file: index.html and another one index.js.

index.html contains a template literal (without quotes)

index.js contanis `const template = fs.readFileSync('index.html')`

Try to evaluate it without eval.

You can say, I could use a templating lib like handlebar or jinja2 but then I could not use javascript as a templating language.

I could also use react but it's too fat for a simple service returning an HTML file.